# Key enter not working inside bootstrap popover input - jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to make input inside bootstrap popover and went I press enter to save the input into the database with ajax but the code with keypress event is not working the popover input but works on input outside the popover.

```
$('.btn-danger').popover({content: "<input type='text' class='form-control' name = 'suma-budzet' id = 'suma-budzet'>", html: true,}); 

$('input').on("keypress", function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
   alert('ya!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the content of the pop-over is not loaded during page-load, you may not directly address the DOM object. Instead use a parent DOM object and to act on keypress event with a selector after the event

```
$('body').on('keypress','#suma-budzet', function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
    alert('ya!');
  }
}
```

It's also better and more specific to address the element by ID and not by tag name

http://api.jquery.com/on/ check the version with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create that as a different function and call that function instead of calling directly. sometimes bootstrap overrides its function rather than using our calls